# Installing k3s offline

Tags: installation, k3s

I am new to Kubernetes.
I would like to install k3s in an offline manner using k3s binary. I can just download install.sh as well and execute it offline to install k3s, is that correct?
When and why would I need airgap images?

Answer (score 2):

My question was not "can I install k3s offline" but "how can I install k3s offline".
To answer my question, we simply need the install script and k3s binary, we do not need airgap images.

Comment: @Mia- can you provide me the link from where I can get k3s binary and download k3s offline without doing any curl to github URLs ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely download the k3s binary and install without connection.
Just take care that most of the instructions available assume you are connected.

Also note the default uninstall script actually deletes the binary. You can easily fix this by removing the specific delete line in the script.

Check the [documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/#installing-k3s-from-the-binary) for binary usage and also note that the script can be instructed to avoid downloading.